# could we have a tag for #tact please?

Tags: discussion

while it might seem automatic that all things interpersonal would intersect with all things tactful, there are times when tact would soften a message too much, a situation is too much of an emergency to have time for tact, or conversely situations demanding extreme levels of tact. could be useful!

Comment: For which question/s? We don't create tags unless they have a question to go on.

Comment: i have to wait 40 minutes to post the question because i asked for the tag first :(

Answer (score 5):

This feels a bit like an extension of [should all things be polite](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/for-questions-should-we-assume-politeness-is-required)? I don't see how [tact] can be the *subject* of a question. If an approach needs a particular degree of *tact* (whatever that means), it should be described in the *body* of the post. But I don't think we need a tag to say "be tactful"* as another way to say "I'm just trying to be polite here". It is simply endemic to this site… unless stated otherwise. Just my opinion.

Comment: my apologies, i misunderstood. i took tags to be like hashtags or keywords, not the subject. i figured the title of the question was probably the subject.